# Find the missing brick

Tags: pattern, visual, progressive-matrix

[image: Find the missing brick]

The pattern made up of figure a-i is missing the last brick. What figure out of the figures in range 1-9 is the last brick to restore the pattern, and why?

*Created by myself*

Comment: I knew I recognized this type of puzzle, I solved one a year ago!

Comment: @Jordan.J.D Yep! "Switch the odd ones out #6"

Answer (score 1):

I have a suggestion as to how to answer it - however identifying which brick fits is tricky and I don't think I've solved that part.

The pattern I think is:

> a and i contain the same patterns, b and h do, c and g, d and f and e is on its own.

Therefore:

> They are allowed to overlap provided that the top piece is the final colour (black or white). So figure 'i' must contain (somehow) a square, a plus sign or horizontal/vertical lines, a circle, something to make up an arrow/an arrow, a half circle.

Comment: My other suggestion is that (rot 13): o naq q pbagnva gur fnzr cnggreaf, p, r naq t pbagnva gur fnzr cnggrea naq gurersber n naq v zhfg nf jryy